# Android GPS cloud of confusion!

Tags: android, gps, emulation, ddms

I am trying to design my first Android application with the use of GPS. As of right now, I have a drawable button that when clicked, alerts a Toast message of the longitude and latitude. I have tried to use the **telnet localhost 5554** and then **geo fix #number #number** to feed in values but no results display just `0` `0`. I have also tried DDMS way of sending GPS coordinates and I get the same thing.

My question is what exactly is the correct way of using the geo fix and the DDMS way of sending coordinates. I have used `Location`, `LocationManger` and `LocationListener` but I am not sure which is the right choice.

Code is given, just in case if the error exists with the code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.track);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    LocationManager location =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location loc = location.getLastKnownLocation(location.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateWithNewLocation(loc);

  }

 private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     updateWithNewLocation(location);
   }

  private void updateWithNewLocation(Location l) {
  longitude = l.getLongitude();
  latitude = l.getLatitude();
  provider = l.getProvider();     
  }

    public void onClick(View v) { 
     Toast.makeText(this, "Your location is " + 
      longitude + " and " + latitude + " provided by: " + 
      provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
   }     
}
```

Comment: Could you please reformat your code? Start every line with 4 spaces, and it will all become one big block.

Comment: What actual problem do you observe? Does it just fail to get any coordinates? Does it return dummy data? Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things

1) Make latitude and longitude volatile

2) Try registering as a listener to the GPS location manager

location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 100, 1, locationListener);

That should get you callbacks sent to your locationListener object.

You can check out some sample Android GPS code here:
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43005

(WARNING! DevX has added a registration landing since I've added this link!)

Comment: The sample code leads to a site with a registration wall. How annoying.

Comment: Yikes!  That is annoying!  Sorry about that, I think devX added the registration landing in the last month or so :-(  Added a warning to the answer.

Comment: To get around the pay wall, paste the url into google search and then click on it.  They can't show a different page to google than to you (through google).

Answer (score 1):

comment the line
 Location loc = location.getLastKnownLocation(location.GPS_PROVIDER);

And test the application by updating gps manually in ddms

if it works, come back to the code then put
Location loc = location.getLastKnownLocation("gps");

Comment: I have tried doing as you suggested back when I had encountered the problem, although now its fixed and is not much of a problem anymore. The reason why it was not working was because I did not register a listener for my location updates. Thank you for replyng anyways.